# CSS :before element is not align with my text

Tags: html, css

I'm using `:before` element to add an image before my text. But it's not aligned.

```css
.page-header:before {
  content: url('../img/page-header.png');
  display: inline-block;
}

.page-header .page-title {
  padding: 0 10px;
  color: #ff4500;
  font-size: 32px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  padding-left: 0px;
}

.page-header .page-sub-title {
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="page-header">
        <span class="page-title">Title</span>
        <br/>
        <span class="page-sub-title">
                        <span>Subtitle</span><br/>
        <span>Introduction Paragraph</span>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Current situation:

[image]

Desired outcome:

[image]

Comment: simple use border left to .page-header class   =====
.page-header {
    border-left: double 4px #000;
    padding-left: 10px;

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="page-header">
                <span class="page-title">Title</span>
                <br/>
                <span class="page-sub-title">
                    <span>Subtitle</span><br/>
                    <span>Introduction Paragraph</span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<style>
    .page-header {
    border-left: double 4px #000;
    padding-left: 10px;

}

.page-header .page-title {
    padding: 0 10px;
    color: #ff4500;
    font-size: 32px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
}

.page-header .page-sub-title {
    font-size: 18px;
}
<style>
```

Insted of using image you can achieve this using "border-left: 4px #000 double;" You don't need any before.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using `position:absolute;height:100%;` on your `:before`.

```css
.page-header {
  padding-left: 15px;
  position: relative;
}

.page-header:before {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-top: 0;
    border-bottom: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 3px;
    
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;

}

.page-header .page-title {
    color: #ff4500;
    font-size: 32px;
}

.page-header .page-sub-title {
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="page-header">
                <span class="page-title">Title</span>
                <br/>
                <span class="page-sub-title">
                    <span>Subtitle</span><br/>
                    <span>Introduction Paragraph</span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
  .page-header:before {
    content: "";
    background-color:red;
    position:absolute;
    height:100%;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width: 4px;

}
.page-header{
  position:relative;
  padding-left:10px;
}

.page-header .page-title {
    padding: 0 10px;
    color: #ff4500;
    font-size: 32px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
}

.page-header .page-sub-title {
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="page-header">
                <span class="page-title">Title</span>
                <br/>
                <span class="page-sub-title">
                    <span>Subtitle</span><br/>
                    <span>Introduction Paragraph</span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

i didn't understand well what you trying to achieve but i managed to get this result! hope this help!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one working fine :)

```css
.page-header{
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 15px;
}
.page-header::before{
  content: '';
  width: 5px;
  height: 100%;
  border-left: 1px solid #ff4500; 
  border-right: 1px solid #ff4500; 
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 5px;
}
.page-header span.page-title {
  padding: 0 10px;
    color: #ff4500;
    font-size: 32px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    display: block;
    font-family: arial;
}
.page-header .page-sub-title span {
  display: block;
  color: #333;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: arial;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="page-header">
                <span class="page-title">Title</span>
                <br/>
                <span class="page-sub-title">
                    <span>Subtitle</span><br/>
                    <span>Introduction Paragraph</span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```